# apache server- how to redirect http to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

I have tried using mod_rewrite in my .htaccess file but this code doesn't work, it just gives me the error "too many redirects"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]` instead of `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: im still getting the same error

Comment: Do you have any other rules in the .htaccess file?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://caetan0.ml/$1 [L,R=301]

    ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /servererror.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using cloudflare or AWS or something similar that loadbalances or internally routes requests for you, you'll need to check the `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}` header instead of the `%{HTTPS}` variable.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```